# Opencv skips frame

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to detect objects in opencv but anything I try, the program does not process all the frames. It skips and only ends up showing one or two frames each time. Even if I try something simple like this:

```py
import cv2

# Open the video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video-4.mp4')

while(1):
    success, frame = cap.read()
    if success:
        cv2.namedWindow("hi", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow('hi', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    else:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It shows the first few frames, and one frame in the middle, and the last frame. I tried similar codes on my friend's computer and it worked. I am not sure what is wrong. Could it be something with my python set up?

Comment: I would rather say it is problem with your computer or system - maybe it is too slow. Do you have problem to see this video in any movie player?

Comment: you don't have to use `namedWindow` - you can use only `imshow`. And if you really need `namedWindow` then you should rather use it only once - at start.

Comment: @furas In movie player the video plays perfectly.

Comment: Why `namedWindow` inside the loop ? Probably it causes that, take namedwindow outside of the loop

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk Hi, I deleted that line and it still skips frames....

Comment: can you count the frames with a counter, also replace `waitKey(0)` with `waitKey(1)`. After counting check the result with real frame number( you can multiply fps with the video duration for real frame number)